# Build a Circle in Android Studio with dynamic Radius

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation

I want to build a Circle shape with some Radius and then radius data (say "r") will get fetched from server/database, the circle should adapt it's size according to the Radius  "r" and my code is fetching data in every 0.1 second, so in every 0.1 second the Radius of circle should change.
The results should look like  circle with dynamic Radius and it's size is changing in every 0.1 second.

I have created  a shape.xml file in drawable folder with circle shaped and with fixed radius. In MainActivity.xml, i created a imageview and set imageview src to that drawable xml file.
Now i am trying to make it's radius dynamic according to tha data fetched. I don't think it's possible in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to draw circle with a customizable radius.

```
class CircleView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.BLUE
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    private var radius = 0f

    fun setRadius(radius: Float) {
        this.radius = radius
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, radius, paint)
    }
}
```